# How do I add an offset to CGContextFillEllipseInRect in CoreGraphics?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-graphics

I want to add top offset to `CGContextFillEllipseInRect`.

When I used `topOffset` equals to zero everything was ok. But when I used not zero offset I got wrong circle.
I tried to set `CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0, topOffset);` but result was the same.

```
float topOffset = 30.f;
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Circle.png"];
CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:img] CGColor]);
CGContextFillEllipseInRect(context, CGRectMake(0, topOffset, img.size.width, img.size.height));
```

without offset

[image]

with top offset

[image]

Comment: Do you intend the pattern image to eventually be something other than a solid color? If not, then just use a solid color instead of a pattern image.

Comment: Yes, my image will be more robust than just a solid color.

Answer (score 3):

`CGContextSetFillColorWithColor` Method ready to fill entire context area of given color value.

when `Stroking or Filling Method` called, Crop given area of stroke or fill.

therefore, you will get Ellipse or Rect or whatever like this...

- First, call CGContextSetFillColorWithColor to set fill color(or pattern color) and FillRect entire area.

[image]

- Second, call CGContexetSetFillColorWithColor to set pattern and Fill with set top, left offset

[image]

Same Background but Crop given area of FillRect() and FillEllipseInRect(),

in your case....

- call `CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:img] CGColor]);` and Fill entire area

[image]

- and when you fill Ellipse with Top-Offset.... looks like this

[image]

that's why your circle looks wrong.

if you want single fill color, try `CGContextSetRGBFillColor` to setting fill color.

EDIT, try this (change CTM before FillColor and Restore before Ellipse Drawing)

```
float topOffset = 30.f;
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Circle.png"];
CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0, topOffset);
CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:img] CGColor]);
CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0, (-1*topOffset);
CGContextFillEllipseInRect(context, CGRectMake(0, topOffset, img.size.width, img.size.height));
```

Sorry for poor English :)

Comment: The function to change the pattern phase (offset) is `CGContextSetPatternPhase()`.

Comment: Jeong Woo Lee, change CTM didn't helped me, but CGContextSetPatternPhase() is working like magic; Ken Thomases thanks